# draw lines to connect two shapes

Tags: connection, wxpython, draw, shapes

How to design such function that user can use mouse to draw a line to connect two shapes? I'm using this module in wxpython  :  wx.lib.ogl.

The doc for theses methods are brief and no good demo that I can learn from.
Does anyone can give me some ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at the wxPython demo? It shows exactly how to do this. It draws several shapes and then connects them with arrows and lines. You can get the wxPython demo from the wxPython website, which I assume you already know since you keep re-posting your questions to the wxPython mailing list.